# Different behavior of mktemp Ubuntu 12.02 / Mint 9 Isadora

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, tmp

In a Bash script I use ImageMagick's convert command for doing some image processing.

I generate a temporal gif file for convert to write to.

I really need the file to have the .gif extension so convert knows that the destination file should be a gif file.

In Ubuntu 12.04 the following works fine:

```
mktemp /tmp/pre_XXXXXXXXXX.gif
```

But in Mint 9 Isadora I get the following error:

```
mktemp: too few X's in template
```

No matter how many X's I throw at it, it yields the same error, which is only fixed when I delete the ".gif" suffix.

**Why is that ? Isn't Mint based on Ubuntu ?**

Comment: That should work, check if `mktemp` is defined as an alias or function: `type mktemp`. Also try `mktemp --tmpdir pre_XXXXXXXXXX.gif`

Comment: To answer your question, yes Mint is based on Ubuntu. But your Mint version is quite old and is based on Ubuntu 10. Your command works on my Mint 15. Maybe the mktemp command changed between the Ubuntu 10 and 12, so between Mint 9 and the latest release of Mint.

Comment: Crossposting? http://askubuntu.com/questions/335414/different-behavior-of-mktemp-ubuntu-12-02-mint-9-isadora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mktemp` is not a standard command and it differs wildly in functionality and options between systems (if the system even has an mktemp command). The only way to know what your `mktemp` accepts is to read its manual on the system in question.

Anyway, you don't need the `.gif` extension to tell imagemagick the result should be a gif file.

```
$ tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/pre_XXXXXX)
$ convert rose: "gif:$tmpfile"
$ file "$tmpfile"
/tmp/pre_MDDsuZ: GIF image data, version 89a, 70 x 46
```